# Why when one member cannot be moved, the whole enclosing class cannot be moved?

Tags: c++, move-constructor

Example

```
struct MyObject {
  MyObject(int value):value(value) { }
  MyObject(MyObject const&o):value(o.value) { }

  int value;
};
```

Assume that the copy constructor does something in addition to be useful. Then

```
std::function<void()> f() {
  MyObject o;
  std::vector<int> v;
  return [=]() { /* use v and o */ &o; &v; }
}
```

`v` and `o` are first copied into the initial lambda object, which is fine. But then they are *again copied* everytime the lambda object needs to be moved. Even though `v` *could* be moved, but it is not. That's because the lambda does not have an implicit move constructor, because `o` does not have a move constructor or trivial copy constructor.

Can someone please explain the rationale behind this?

Comment: It sounds like this is a question defaulted move constructors (and assignment operators?), you might want to include those terms in the question.

Comment: Probably because nobody though you would need to build closures like that. Like a lot of C++ features they are designed to solve one problem now we are pushing them to see where they can be used which is completely different from the original concept. I am sure we will iron out the chinks to C++11 in C++25.

Comment: @LokiAstari I assume you mean 2125

Comment: Isn't this just the same reason for which a class doesn't get an implicit move constructor if it has an unmovable member?

Comment: I dealt with this issue by wrapping variables in mover class, which moves in non-const copy ctor: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++.moderated/browse_thread/thread/ba5f0cd7ded28b68/c35eb3c76036dc66

Comment: I think the rationale is simple, as soon as there is one unmovable member all other cannot be moved or invariant will be broken when they throw.

Comment: @kerrek yes you successfully repeated the title of this question :-)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Wait, then we have to clarify: Are you asking why lambdas behave like classes, or why classes with non-movable members don't get a move constructor?

Comment: @kerrek the lambda thing was just an example. i am asking about the latter

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I don't quite understand the confusion. So, first off, if a class has a copy constructor, but a deleted move constructor, then moving it is not allowed: `Foo a(std::move(b));` is an error. This is despite the fact that rvalues bind to constant references. Now, the implicitly generated functions just perform their action member wise, so implicit move moves member-wise. If any member has a deleted move constructor, you cannot move it, and hence you can't move the whole class.

Comment: @kerrek i did never talk about a deleted move ctor. but about an absent move ctor. the member would just use its copy constructor and all would be fine.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I think defining a copy constructor and *not* defining a move constructor automatically makes the move constructor deleted; then the above applies.

Comment: @Kerrek you are wrong :) in such a case no move ctor is declared at all, not even a deleted one (that would break so many C++03 code that it's not even funny). It's the other way around: If you explicitly declare a *move* constructor but not a copy constructor, then a deleted copy constructor is implicitly declared.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I see - yes, I got that wrong. I think GCC's error message may be helpful: "non-static data member ‘***’ does not have a move constructor or trivial copy constructor". So the only way you get a default move constructor is if the members have either explicit move constructors or trivial copy constructors -- i.e. if the members have an implicitly declared move constructor.

Comment: @kerrek thanks. tho you again repeated more or less the ending of my second last paragraph of my question :-)

Answer (score 6):

I seem to recall that this is a compromise between the two extremes, those who did not want implicit generation of move constructors at all, and those that wanted move constructors to be generated automatically in *most* circumstances.

Among the people that wanted no implicit generation of move constructors, Dave Abrahams wrote an article called *[Implicit Move Must Go](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/10/implicit-move-must-go/)*. The rationale there is that under some circumstances, even if the members are *movable*, the implicit generation of a move constructor can break invariants.

Early this year (2011) the committee decided to keep implicit generation of move constructors in a decision that seemed to emphasize performance boost in existing code over safety issues <sup>(1)</sup>, and again Dave [blogged](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/02/w00t-w00t-nix-nix/) about it. It does not talk about the specifics of the decision, the pros and cons, but is not quite happy with the result either.

Edit (from Jerry Coffin): Here's the list of conditions for implicit declaration of a move constructor:

```
If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor, 
one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
— X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
— X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
— X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
— X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
— the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.
```

The basic idea is that inclusion of any of these in the class is an indication that an implicitly generated move ctor is likely to mis-behave. While that's true, the conditions in the list are neither necessary nor sufficient to the determination, so many move ctors that would have been useful aren't generated, and many that will cause problems can be generated. Worse, the rules are already long and complex enough that few remember them all, and fixing them would probably at least double that.
[end of Jerry's contribution/rant]

<sup>(1)</sup> Thanks to Gene Bushuyev for the insight as to why the decision was taken

Comment: I wouldn't call the decision political, I think the consideration that  with implicit move a lot of existing code wouldn't need any changes to get a performance boost prevailed over safety.

Comment: @dribeas: Hope you don't mind the edit -- I didn't really have a lot to add about the original question, but the number and complexity of conditions under which a move ctor can/will be generated seemed relevant to the objections. It's probably also worth mentioning that the last condition is itself really another list of conditions even longer than those above.

Comment: @JerryCoffin By no means, I was going to thank you for it, but did not think that a comment with the (at) syntax would notify you :)

Comment: It appears cpp-next.com has been offline for a while. The *Implicit Move Must Go* may be [reproduced on open-std.org](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3153.htm) and the blog may be only [available through web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130917233657/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/02/w00t-w00t-nix-nix/)

Answer (score 1):

Kinda guessing, but I suspect it may have to do with exceptions. That is, move constructors should really be noexcept, but having a move constructor call a copy constructor could have it throw.

(trying to refresh my memory from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3201.pdf), which I think covered this issue)

**EDITED TO ADD**:

And my guess was wrong. The correct answer, as far as I can tell, is from [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/move.pdf). The presence of the copy constructor is an indication that the class has invariants, and the default generated move constructor might not respect those invariants, and therefor, should not be generated.

Comment: Ah thanks sir that makes sense. A lambda has no invariants. do you think it should have always a move constructor?

Comment: If it had todo with exceptions they would not require a trivial copy consttuxtor, but a noexcept copy constructor.

Comment: Hmm hold on. the presence of a copy constructor of a member indicates that the member has invariants, but those would still be respected because the *member* will never be moved

Comment: I don't see why exceptions should matter. If there's an exception, there's an exception, so what. That's just normal behaviour. Move exceptions are predominantly relevant in `vector` which wants to perform silent moves that mustn't fail.